# Detect QML component overlapped with other item

Tags: qt, qml

I have multiple loaded components stacked one top of another.
if One loaded component is overlapping on other component , is there any way we can detect the number of items in the component is overlapped by other component.

visible property is not working in this scenario.

Comment: Don't think so. You will likely have to iterate over all the components, take their bounding rectangle (x, y, width, height) and perform intersection tests between them.

Comment: by "components" do you mean QWidgets? And by overlap, do you mean 100% overlay, or partial? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedlayout.html *might* help.

Comment: Use the Layout Features of QML
https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtquick-components-symbian-1.1/qt-components-scalability-guidelines-layout-features.html

Answer (score 0):

Iterate (recursively) QQuickItem::childItems() in C++ would be one way, as suggested. For event delivery we use QQuickItemPrivate::paintOrderChildItems(), which just sorts the same list by z-order; but it's private API.  Alteratively there is QQuickItem::childAt(x, y).  dumpItemTree() is for debugging.  The docs for that also show you how to visit all items recursively in QML: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qml-qtquick-item.html#dumpItemTree-method